# Unit test with jest, test tap and map

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-spectator

I have problems testing tap and map with jest, I am using spectator.
Does anyone know how I can make it go through this part of the code?

```
private caseEMPLOYEE_ID($ObservableData: Observable<any>, ctrl: any) {
$ObservableData = this.employeeControllerService.getAllEmployeesUsingGet(ctrl.value ? { 'nameOrId.contains': ctrl.value } : {}).pipe(
  tap((response) => this.checkResultSize(response)),
  map((res: any) =>
    this.mapResultsByKey(
      res.content.map((obj) => ({ ...obj, idName: obj.emplid + ' - ' + obj.name })),
      ctrl
    )
  )
);
return $ObservableData;
```

}

This is the test

[Code test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UojPS.png)

I have not been able to paste the test code as it gives me a format error.

Thank you very much and best regards.

Comment: How would you normally check in tests whether functions/methods have been called and what they were called with?

Comment: Is there any errors that you are receiving or additional information to have a better understanding? It would be super if you included your code as code and not image links.